# Cassandra pyspark : how to filter a timpstamp range using lambda

Tags: apache-spark, lambda, cassandra

currently, I use cassandra pyspark shell to run my python code , I want to filter a time range (e.g. select * from XXXX where time< 2016-08-30 12:00:00+0000 ). from my cassandra database to calculate the max glass_id. I use this line :

```
sc.cassandraTable("poc", "dream").select("glass_id").filter(lambda r:datetime.fromtimestamp( r["glass_start_time"])<datetime(2016, 8, 30, 12, 0, tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzoffset(None, 0))).map(lambda r: (r["glass_id"], 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b).collect()
```

to filter a time range (e.g. select * from XXXX where time< 2016-08-30 12:00:00+0000 ).
table structure is like

```
CREATE TABLE poc.dream (
    glass_start_time timestamp,
    product_id text,
    step_id text,
    glass_id text,
    ...
    ...
PRIMARY KEY (glass_start_time, product_id, step_id, glass_id)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (product_id ASC, step_id ASC, glass_id ASC)
```

but this lines cannot work. 
the tracing is:

```
    org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/spark/

python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2346, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2346, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 317, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1776, in combineLocally
    merger.mergeValues(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 236, in mergeValues
    for k, v in iterator:
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "./TargetHolding_pyspark-cassandra-0.3.5.jar/pyspark_cassandra/types.py", line 130, in __getitem__
    return self.__getattr__(name)
  File "./TargetHolding_pyspark-cassandra-0.3.5.jar/pyspark_cassandra/types.py", line 137, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: glass_start_time

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:342)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/04/28 16:08:09 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.1 in stage 14.0 (TID 779, localhost, partition 3,ANY, 5629 bytes)
17/04/28 16:08:09 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 777) on executor localhost: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException (Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2346, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2346, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 317, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1776, in combineLocally
    merger.mergeValues(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 236, in mergeValues
    for k, v in iterator:
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "./TargetHolding_pyspark-cassandra-0.3.5.jar/pyspark_cassandra/types.py", line 130, in __getitem__
    return self.__getattr__(name)
  File "./TargetHolding_pyspark-cassandra-0.3.5.jar/pyspark_cassandra/types.py", line 137, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: glass_start_time
) [duplicate 1]
17/04/28 16:08:09 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.1 in stage 14.0 (TID 780, localhost, partition 2,ANY, 5608 bytes)
17/04/28 16:08:09 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 775) in 2525 ms on localhost (2/4)
17/04/28 16:08:10 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.1 in stage 14.0 (TID 779) on executor localhost: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException (Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2346, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2346, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 317, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1776, in combineLocally
    merger.mergeValues(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 236, in mergeValues
    for k, v in iterator:
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "./TargetHolding_pyspark-cassandra-0.3.5.jar/pyspark_cassandra/types.py", line 130, in __getitem__
    return self.__getattr__(name)
  File "./TargetHolding_pyspark-cassandra-0.3.5.jar/pyspark_cassandra/types.py", line 137, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
```